# Struts 2 - Passing parameters between action are lost when second action works with form

Tags: java, struts2, parameter-passing, chain, model-driven

I have two action classes which work with same model over `ModelDriven` interface.
**Every action class works with form**. 
I need to store values to same model in both actions.

From first action class(after validation), I pass modeldriven model into second class through:

```
@Result(name = "success", location = "action2", type = "chain")
```

In second action class, I show values, which has been store into model in first action.

This works fine, but when I execute form submit in second action, stored values
from first action are lost.

**So, data from first action are stored only for first call second action.**

Is there any solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your data into the session or use parameters with a result as described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Parameters+in+configuration+results) and [there](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/convention/#result-annotation).

> Parameters can be passed to results using the params attribute. The value of this attribute is a string array with an even number of elements in the form {"key0", "value0, "key1", "value1" ... "keyN", "valueN"}. For example:

> ```
>  @Action(value="/different/url",
> ```

```
    results={@Result(name="success", type="httpheader", params={"status", "500", "errorMessage", "Internal Error"})}
  )
```

Comment: @AndreaLigios Why we avoid Chain Result? Shall i know the reason

Comment: Cannot edit comment, so adding an updated link to action chaining in a new comment: http://struts.apache.org/docs/action-chaining.html